# Spring Dataflow not display properties

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-properties

When I create Task in Spring Cloud `Dataflow` and edit properties in Spring Cloud `Dataflow` Dashboard I only see standard properties `label` despite being configured
`ConfigurationProperties`. And I do not know what I've set up wrongly. Below the code.

**JobProps:**

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("job")
public class JobProps {

    private String ux;
//getter and setter
}
```

**JobDoing:**

```
@Component
public class JobDoing {

    public JobDoing() {
        doing();
    }

    @Value("${job.ux:}")
    private String test;

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(JobConfiguration.class);

    public void doing(){
            logger.info("Props: " + test);
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication:**

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JobProps.class })
@EnableTask
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you do it as expected? I asked this quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59412806/spring-cloud-data-flow-custom-application-properties as I cannot see my custom properties

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist your application's custom configuration properties so that they get picked up by the Spring Cloud Data Flow server when extracting and displaying the application configuration properties.

To whitelist the configuration properties, you can refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-whitelisting) documentation.